# Why are my ASCII integer values becoming negative?

Tags: c, encryption, ascii

I am trying to do a very basic form of encryption and decryption by using operations on ASCII characters in C. I have the following code:

```
char* myEncrypt(char* stringToEncrypt)
{
    char *encryptedString = malloc(256);
    strcpy(encryptedString, stringToEncrypt);

    int publicKey = 50;

    for (int i = 0; encryptedString[i] && encryptedString[i] != '\n'; ++i)
            encryptedString[i] = (encryptedString[i] + publicKey) % 256;

    return encryptedString;
}
```

My issue is that when I run this code I am every so often getting negative values for my integer values of the ASCII characters assigned to encryptedString[i]. This is causing the decryption to fail. Looking at the code there should be no way for me to get negative values since I am using the modulo operation. Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? I can't see anything in the function that is causing the problem. The original declaration of `stringToEncrypt` and its contents prior to being passed to your function seem like a likely source (unless of course `stringToEncrypt` is NULL or doesn't contain a *nul-terminating* char).

Comment: Because `char` is signed on your system?

Comment: Why do you have `% 256`? ASCII has only 128 code units (all 0 to 127). Many string encryption algorithms actually operate on a byte array and return a byte array because there is no intention to always return a string that is valid in any character encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many implementations use signed characters for plain `char`s.  If you need the characters to be unsigned, then you'll need to use `unsigned char`.

For example, if you have a `char` value of 100, and you add 50, you get 150. If `CHAR_MAX` value is 127 (typical), then you end up with an implementation-defined value being assigned back to your character -- most likely wrapping around to -106.

Also, in C, a negative value will still be negative after a modulo operation.  For example: `-50 % 256` is `-50`.  So if your original string had characters that were less than -50, you would end up with negative values after adding 50 and taking modulo 256 as well.